# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop Installer - Stuck on Active Directory page, doesn't like my domain name value?

Tags: system-installation, active-directory

So, I'm installing 22.04 desktop and I get to the "Who Are You" page, fill in username/password/etc on there, and I check the "use Active Directory" checkbox at the bottom of that page and go to this next page, which I fill out the three fields below and click the Test Connection button and get a green checkmark:

[everything looks ok at this point.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B213W.png)

But then I click the "Continue" button on that page and it highlights my domain name value as shown below and doesn't let me proceed, and the Back button is disabled, so I appear to be stuck:

[stuck on this domain page of the installation.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoTxH.png)

Any idea what is wrong here, because it's not very helpful, no message or hint of any kind indicating WHY it doesn't like my domain name value.

Thanks in advance.

edit: a couple of additional relevant details:

- My domain name is nothing crazy, literally just [a-z] characters (length:14 characters), just all lowercase alpha + ".net"
- This linux machine is a VM on an on-prem HP DL380p Gen8 host running ESXi 6.0
- I pre-staged the computer account in AD for this machine, added an entry in DNS Manager for it, and can ping it from the Windows Domain Controller by both ip address and dns name

Comment: Did you find a solution? Exact same situation here, only it's a VM on a Proxmox host with a Samba 4 domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you ran into the same issue, but this solved it for me:

As I didn't want to use my domain user name *andi* as local admin user (the first user with sudo rights), I chose *admin*. Then continued to Domain setup and got stuck like you.

Hence, I tried to install only with local user and join the domain after install. I also chose *admin* as first local user, but the installer complained: *admin* is a reserved user!

Then I remembered, I had the same issue with another box before and looked up my notes. There I used *ladmin* (local) for the first user and then could join the domain in the installer without an issue!

Obviously this is a but in the input validation, when the *join domain* checkbox is selected in the user config screen.

Answer (score 0):

A frustrating issue... I ran into the same issue but was trying to use "admin" on the previous page as a local user. It doesn't give you an error, and the worst part is you can't click "Back" button to go change it. Small stuff like this makes it more and more difficult for techs to adopt Linux into their wretched Windows networks.